# Access 2003 - How to display an image from url?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on a Access 2003 Form Report project.
I couldn't find a solution to create a QR CODE in Access 2003 Form Report.

So, I add an image/picture object to form but it does work only with local path images.

Is there any way to use it as getting pictures from a web link?

Basicly, i want to display a dynamic image from web link at Access Report Form.

Here is an example link for image:  https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&choe=UTF-8&chs=200x200&chl=https://www.google.com

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method used in my project [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl) using this function:

```vb
' Download (picture) file from a URL of a hyperlink field to a
' (temporary) folder, and return the full path to the downloaded file.
'
' This can be used as the control source for a bound picture control.
' If no Folder is specified, the user's IE cache folder is used.
'
' Typical usage in the RecordSource for a form or report where Id is
' the unique ID and Url is the hyperlink field holding the URL to
' the picture file to be displayed:
'
'   - to a cached file where parameter Id is not used:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent(0, [Url]) As Path From SomeTable;
'
'   - or, where Id is used to create the local file name:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent([Id], [Url], "d:\somefolder") As Path From SomeTable;
'
' Then, set ControlSource of the bound picture control to: Path
'
' 2017-05-28. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function UrlContent( _
    ByVal Id As Long, _
    ByVal Url As String, _
    Optional ByVal Folder As String) _
    As Variant

    Const NoError   As Long = 0
    Const Dot       As String = "."
    Const BackSlash As String = "\"
    
    Dim Address     As String
    Dim Ext         As String
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim Result      As String
    
    ' Strip leading and trailing octothorpes from URL string.
    Address = HyperlinkPart(Url, acAddress)
    ' If Address is a zero-length string, Url was not wrapped in octothorpes.
    If Address = "" Then
        ' Use Url as is.
        Address = Url
    End If
    
    If Folder = "" Then
        ' Import to IE cache.
        Result = DownloadCacheFile(Address)
    Else
        If Right(Folder, 1) <> BackSlash Then
            ' Append a backslash.
            Folder = Folder & BackSlash
        End If
    
        ' Retrieve extension of file name.
        Ext = StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(Address), Dot)(0))
        ' Build full path for downloaded file.
        Path = Folder & CStr(Id) & Dot & Ext
        
        If DownloadFile(Address, Path) = NoError Then
            Result = Path
        End If
    End If
    
    UrlContent = Result
    
End Function
```

Your example:

[image]